# how join list tuple and dict into a dict?

Tags: python

how join list tuple and dict into a dict?

```
['f','b','c','d'] (1,2,3) and {'a':'10'}
d excluded for list be compatible with the tuple

output {'f':'1','b':'2','c':'3','a':'10'}
```

Comment: there is no good way to do this in general. Are there any conditions that you can give?

Comment: The output is not a valid dictionary: it has duplicate keys. You should also make the logic between putting together the data from the list and the tuple clearer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make a `dict` from keys and values like so:

```
keys = ['a','b','c','d']
values = (1,2,3)
result = dict(zip(keys, values)) # {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Then you can update it with another dict

```
result.update({ 'f' : 5 })
print result # {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'f': 5}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
dict(zip(a_list, a_tuple)).update(a_dictionary)
```

when a_list is your list, a_tuple is your tuple and a_dictionary is your dictionary.

**EDIT:**
If you really wanted to turn the numbers in you tuple into strings than first do:

```
new_tuple = tuple((str(i) for i in a_tuple))
```

and pass new_tuple to the zip function.

Answer (score 1):

This will accomplish the first part of your question:

```
dict(zip(['a','b','c','d'], (1,2,3)))
```

However, the second part of your question would require a second definition of 'a', which the dictionary type does not allow. However, you can always set additional keys manually:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['e'] = 10
>>> d
{'e':10}
```

Answer (score 0):

The keys in a dictionary must be unique, so this part: `{'a':'1','a':'10'}` is impossible.

Here is code for the rest:

```
l = ['a','b','c','d']
t = (1,2,3)

d = {}
for key, value in zip(l, t):
    d[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
>>> dict({'a':'10'}.items() + (zip(['f','b','c','d'],('1','2','3'))))
{'a': '10', 'c': '3', 'b': '2', 'f': '1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since noone has given an answer that converts the tuple items to str yet

```
>>> L=['f','b','c','d']
>>> T=(1,2,3)
>>> D={'a':'10'}
>>> dict(zip(L,map(str,T)),**D)
{'a': '10', 'c': '3', 'b': '2', 'f': '1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> t = (1,2,3)
>>> d = {'a':'10'}
>>> t = map(str, t)  # the OP has requested str values, let's do this first
```

If you are OK with mutating the original dict, then you can just do this:

```
>>> d.update(zip(l, t))
```

or in Python 3.9+ ([PEP 584](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/)):

```
>>> d |= zip(l, t)
```

But if you need to keep the original `d` intact:

```
>>> new_d = dict(zip(l, t))
>>> new_d |= d
```